# Free 3 of 9 BarCode Not Scanning

Tags: asp.net, barcode-printing

Hello every one here i am Generating a BarCode using Font  Free 3 of 9 like this in a .rdlc Report Page.

```xml
<Textbox Name="ID">
    <rd:DefaultName>ID</rd:DefaultName>
    <Top>1.1in</Top>
    <Width>1.15 in</Width>
    <Style>
        <FontFamily>Free 3 of 9</FontFamily>
        <FontSize>28pt</FontSize>
        <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
        <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
        <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
        <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
        <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
    </Style>
    <ZIndex>6</ZIndex>
    <Left>2.26406in</Left>
    <Height>0.59063in</Height>
    <Value>= "*" &amp; Fields!ID.Value &amp; "*" </Value>
</Textbox>
```

But the Scanner i have isn't reading it its not scanning it at all. Can any one help where is the error. Its a ID that gets to be printed and should be Scan able but its doesn't Scan. what other Font could Replace it ? It creates the BarCode looks fine prints and every thing Converts to PDF but doesn't Scan.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your barcode ends in "62462", then all the bars and spaces that describe the previous characters are missing, including the initial "*" start symbol. In other words, the png file in the link above only shows the right hand side of the barcode, but I can't tell how much of the left or "start" of the barcode is cut off. I'm guessing the barcode is being clipped by some bounding rectangle.

Increase the width that you give the image generated by the textbox, and you may be okay.

When working with Code 3 of 9, the start and end of the barcode has a very distinctive look because of the asterisks on each side of the data. It looks like this:

[image]

If you work with Code 39 long enough, you'll recognize a code 39 barcode a mile away because of the symbol associated with the asterisks. Thin bar, thick space, then thin, thick, thick, thin bars separated by thin spaces.